# JavaScript applying conditions and functions

Tags: javascript, function, math, boolean, operators

I have to create IF conditions based on the following rules in javascript. if you can please help:

1. Sum of main numbers should equal sum of other numbers within limits

```js
//First example
    var a = 5;  //asume a is sum of main numbers
    var b = 10; // b is sum of other numbers

    var limit = 11;  //limit
      
    if ((a==b) < limit)  //something like this
          alert("true"); 
    else
         alert("false");
         
    //It should return false as a is not equal b but within limit but it is not working.
    
    //Second example
         
    var a = 15; 
    var b = 17; 
    var limit = 11;
    
    
    if ((a==b) < limit) 
          alert("true"); 
    else
         alert("false");
    
    //third example
    var a = 15; 
    var b = 17; 
    var limit = 11;
    
    
    if ((a==b) < limit) 
          alert("true"); 
    else
         alert("false");
```

How do I create the if conditions in JavaScript which will return booleans true or false based on above rule. Can I use some built in maths function here like 
 Math.abs etc.

Comment: do you have an example of the wanted result?

Comment: I found the following is also an answer to the above., but not sure how. If yes, can anyone explain?

Math.abs(a - b) < limit;

Comment: actually your prblm isn't described well. what do you expect for the three cases?

Comment: `(a==b) < limit` makes no sense.... You are comparing a boolean with less than a number.  `a==b` is `false` so you have `false < limit`

Comment: Simply , what the rule says, i need to implement that. it should be true based on the rule i.e. Sum of main numbers should equal sum of other numbers within limits

Answer (score 2):

What you *probably* want is this:

```
if ((a===b) && a < limit)
```

Update: As pointed out in comments, if `a== b` and `a < limit`, `b` has to be `< limit`, so no need to check that.

Comment: if that's correct, then one of those 3 conditions is redundant

Comment: `if (a === b && a < limit)`

Answer (score 1):

Java script will first interpret `a == b` as a boolean (true or false), which will result in this for example one:

```
if ((false) < limit)  //cannot compare a boolean with a number
          alert("true"); 
    else
         alert("false");
```

You cannot compare a boolean with a number. You would need to add another operator to also check that the value of a is less than the limit.

```
if ((a===b) && (a < limit))  //something like this
          alert("true"); 
    else
         alert("false");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `(a==b) < limit` is that javascript understand `false < limit`

You have to used AND operator for do something like this `(a === b) && a < limit && b < limit`

You should use `===` operator for test type in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((a===b) && a < limit)
```

The Javascript does not support (==) because it has its own syntax. If you need to work on Javascript you need to learn its syntax as well

Answer (score -1):

I found the following is also an answer to the above., but not sure how. If yes, can anyone explain?

```
Math.abs(a - b) < limit;
```